# libcURL CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE

Tags: c, libcurl

Is there a way to get libcURL to accept a key that is not a "PEM", "DER", or "ENG" file? I would like to be able to verify the client with the server but I am unable to aquire the PEM key. I have a cert file in .txt format that I can place in the key database. Does anyone know of a way this can be done?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to provide the key in a format that libcurl knows and speaks (which in turn is mandated by the SSL library your libcurl version is using).